# How does ReactJS evaluate any JavaScript Expression inside JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

The ReactJS documentation says something interesting and powerful about what their JSX is capable of:

> You can embed any JavaScript expression in JSX by wrapping it in curly
>   braces.  For example, `2 + 2`, `user.firstName`, and `formatName(user)` are all valid expressions.

https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx

This is so powerful and interesting to me because this isn't possible in AngularJS, nor EmberJS.  Angular uses Angular Expressions in their markup, and EmberJS uses Handlebar Expressions their markup.

**Q1)** How does ReactJS achieve reading *any* JS Expression inside JSX?

**Q2)** Do they use eval() under the hood?

Comment: I can't give you an in-depth answer, because I'm no expert on React internals. However, maybe things can be cleared up by reading this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html and the link to the babel compiler there. `React.createElement` takes any number of arguments which I believe are are executed, appended and returned. I did a quick search, but there's no `eval` in the distributed React files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSX is [a Babel plugin](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) which transforms your sourcecode ahead of time, not during runtime.
Understanding this allows us to see both why [Yuri's answer is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48700855/1470607), as well as how JSX can evaluate arbitrary expressions.

As a short prefix, [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is a commonly used Javascript compiler, which, depending on your configuration, allows you to do a number of useful things. A very common example is transpiling ES6 features so the code can be used in ES5 environments:

Code in:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(n => n * 2);
```

Code out:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(function (n) {
  return n * 2;
});
```

The JSX Babel plugin does something similar, it transforms the easily readable JSX syntax into React function calls (or other similar things if you're not using it with React).

[From their own demo](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/), code in:

```
var profile = <div>
  <img src="avatar.png" className="profile" />
  <h3>{[user.firstName, user.lastName].join(' ')}</h3>
</div>;
```

Code out:

```
var profile = React.createElement("div", null,
  React.createElement("img", { src: "avatar.png", className: "profile" }),
  React.createElement("h3", null, [user.firstName, user.lastName].join(" "))
);
```

Understanding this, it is now easy to see that 1) any expressions can be used because the expressions are not evaluated at all; and 2) `eval` is not required at all — the code is transformed ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks for your clear and direct answer.  Yes, I see how React achieves it with the help of the Babel plugin: The JS Expression within the JSX curly braces is transpiled to an argument of `React.createElement()`.

Answer (score 1):

React doesn't evalute anything. You just need to take a look at compiled code. JSX is just a syntax extension that is converted to plain old js evaluated by engine.

```
() => <div>{2 + 2}</div>
```

becomes just a function that calls `React.createElement`

```
function () {
  return React.createElement(
    "div",
    null,
    2 + 2
  );
};
```

Comment: This response provides both useful & helpful information, but doesn't answer the questions directly.  If you answer in light of the questions, it could be improved.

Comment: @MichaelR What is not clear from my answer? React doesn't evaluate anything - answers your first question and makes the second one redundant because again it **doesn't evaluate anything at all**. BTW jsx is not even react specific